# Proving existence and uniqueness of solution to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to prove existence and uniqueness of the solution to the following equations:

$f'_0(t)=-\lambda_0f_0(t)$

$f'_n(t)=-\lambda_n f_n(t)+\lambda_{n-1}f_{n-1}(t), n=1,2,...$

where $\lambda_n\geq0$ and $f_n(0)\geq0 $ for all n.

I prove by induction that  $f_n(t)\geq0 $ for all $t\geq0$.

I have no idea where to start. I appreciate any help.

Comment: The only problem should be the positivity. Can you show that $f_1$ is positive? This should then generalize to an induction proof.

Comment: Yes, i did it. But what should i use to argue that it proofs existence and uniqueness?

Comment: No initial conditions specified? How do you prove uniqueness without them?

Comment: For the collection $(f_0,...,f_n)$ you have a linear system with constant coefficients. This is a standard case where Picard-Lindelöf applies in the widest sense.

Comment: A one dimensional (suitable smooth) ode cannot pass through an equilibrium.

Comment: I fixed my conditions. Now that's all  initial conditions which i got in my problem.

Comment: When you say "I prove by induction that $\ f_n(t)\ge0\ $ for all $\ t\ge0\ $" do you really that mean you've *already* proved it, or are you asking for assistance with that proof?

Comment: I already proved it, now i have problem with uniqueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditions you have given are insufficient to guarantee that their solution will be unique. Suppose $\ \lambda_0\ne0\ $, but $\ \lambda_n=0\ $ for all $\ n\ge1\ $ for instance.   Then the conditions have the trivial solution
$$
f_n(t)=0
$$
for all $\ n\ $, but also the non-trivial solution
\begin{align}
f_0(t)&=e^{-\lambda_0t}\\
f_1(t)&=1-e^{-\lambda_0t}\\
f_n(t)&=0
\end{align}
for all $\ n\ge2\ $ (or any positive multiple of it).

In the general case, if you set
\begin{align}
\mathbf{g}_n(t)&=\pmatrix{f_0(t)\\f_1(t)\\\vdots\\f_n(t)}\ \text{, and}\\
\Lambda_n&=\pmatrix{-\lambda_0&0&0&\dots&0&0\\
\lambda_0&-\lambda_1&0&\dots&0&0\\
0&\lambda_1&-\lambda_2&\dots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&\lambda_{n-1}&-\lambda_n}\ ,
\end{align}
then you can write the differential equations in vector form as
$$
\mathbf{g}_n'(t)=\Lambda_n\mathbf{g}_n(t)\ .
$$
This has the solution
\begin{align}
\mathbf{g}_n(t)&=e^{\Lambda_n t}\mathbf{g}_n(0)\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{t^k\Lambda_n^k}{k!}\right)\mathbf{g}_n(0)\ .\ 
\end{align}
which is unique if $\ \mathbf{g}_n(0)\ $ is uniquely specified, but not otherwise.

Perhaps what you are required to do is to show that the solution is unique for any *given* $\ f_1(0),$$ f_2(0), \dots,$$ f_n(0), \dots\ $, but if that is the case, the question should have been more clearly worded.